# Update date time column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to update a `DateTime` filed with value like `2008-04-22 00:00:00.000` and add a fixed time to it + `1 Hour`

example i have the column like `2008-04-22 00:00:00.000` to be like `2008-04-22 01:00:00.000`

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Easy:

```
UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET YourColumn = DATEADD(H, 1, YourColumn)
WHERE (some condition here)
```

[`DATEADD`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) is a handy method to add or subtract any kind of amount of seconds, minutes, days even from a `DATETIME` value

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE TableName SET ColumnName=DATEADD(hh, 1, ColumnName)
```

Where `TableName` is your table, and `ColumnName` is a datetime column

Answer (score 1):

Update DateTime column with `00:00:00` Time - Keep Date unchanged, only time changes

```
update [EmployeeSchedule] 
set [SchedDate] = CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), [SchedDate], 102) + ' 00:00:00')
```